# I have a Dataframe like this.I have to find duplicate value from the column.Step by Step questions below

Tags: python, pandas, analysis

[pandas dataframe#As in Name Column Anil is working on(01-JAn-17,02Jan,03Jan,04Jan,05Jan,27Jan and 28JAn) and Vimal on (1,2 and 27Jan) and Dinkar in (3 and 5th Jan)only.SO Create a new column from day_working column to a new column with all day of the most(like in this example for Anil)

## Step 1: new column total Day_work_emp, with day from Anil is highest, So the column will be like a list of working as (1,2,3,4,5,27 and 28Jan)

## Step 2: now to assing value zero value(0) in Fare for vimal on(3,4,5,27,28) as vimal contain the value for (1,2 Jan) , same for Dinkar also as (1,2,4,27 and 28) as zero(0) value in Fare.

## Step 3: Callin only the value for For Anil and Vimal , or Dinkar and Anil .][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0zU9.png)

Comment: 1) Please fix your explanation... It's a little hard to understand. 2) Your column names are not consistent 3) You've not made your expected output clear. 4) You haven't shown what you've tried, and I'm assuming this is homework?

Comment: show your code and full error message.